# Drupal alternative for prettyprinting SQL results?

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-views

Drupal seems to do two main things:

1. Create SQL queries to pull data you want.
2. Site design, incuding prettyprinting SQL query results.

The problems:

1. It can't use existing SQL tables; it must import tables into its 
   own format.
2. Manipulating "Create View" to get the query you want can be 
   frustrating, especially if you already know the query! I realize you 
   can type in a query directly, but you're 
   really not "supposed" to do that.

I can create complexish SQL queries myself, so I really just need a 
prettyprinter/site designer.

What product can prettyprint queries on existing tables? Example 
queries (scroll to bottom of each page to see query):

http://798d4dab518a91787e0e0be5c94f8bb1.ccgames.db.94y.info/ 
http://57442d9ce4c5063869883519f2a9cd0f.ccgames.db.94y.info/ 
http://9160fe29e3da336652ec98fbf7f2aeef.ccgames.db.94y.info/ 
http://a782c6b9be09f375e5f1b1d69f1e7c62.ccgames.db.94y.info/

Of course, I'd like hardcoded strings (like 'barrycarter') 
"templated". In other words "drupal.foo.com/?p=xxx" would run the 
query w/ "xxx" instead of "barrycarter".

Thoughts? Any way to coerce Drupal into doing what I want?

See also: [Converting constantly updated SQLite3 db into Drupal site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575440/converting-constantly-updated-sqlite3-db-into-drupal-site/)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the table wizard module. It lets you use existing / non-Drupal tables with views, including support for relationships between tables.

P.S: I 100% disagree with your assertions re: what drupal is.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the 'data' module (which replaces table wizard), but Drupal folks say that it integrates poorly with Drupal, although this may be OK in my case. OK, from a techie viewpoint, what is Drupal? I could have it wrong.

Comment: It's a content management system. SQL is just the persistence layer, not the point of the app.